# Can NodeJS fs module access the Network drives of another computer connected via LAN/Ethernet

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, fs

I am running my NodeJS App(Express application) on a Raspberry pi. 
I am able to access the Application/website on another computer connected via Lan/Ethernet with the Raspberry pi by going to it's(pi) IP address(WLAN) followed by the port number on a browser(chrome). Since both are connected to the same wifi.

1. I want to know can I access the website by simply going to the IP Address(Eth) of the pi to make sure it works even if there's no internet connection.
2. I wanted to know if the node app running on Raspberry pi can access the network drives or any folders of the connected computer with the help of the FS module.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know can I access the website by simply going to the IP Address(Eth) of the pi to make sure it works even if there's no internet connection.

Yes.  If the IP address of the Pi computer is accessible from whatever computer you're on (on the same network), then you can access the web server on the Pi using the IP address.T

> I wanted to know if the node app running on Raspberry pi can access the network drives or any folders of the connected computer with the help of the FS module.

The `fs` module should be able to see any network drive that you can see from the Pi terminal.  In other words, the `fs` module supports whatever the host OS is configured to support.  You will have to see if your Pi is configured to see the network drives you want to see or not.

To see Windows shared drives, you will likely need SAMBA support installed and configured on the Pi.  See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/samba.md for more info.

Comment: What did you mean by "on the same network"(first line of the answer)? Can I access the website if there's no internet/wifi, just two computers connected together via an Ethernet cable by simply going to the IP address of the pi?

Comment: @AryanArora - If you just have two computers connected by an internet cable and no actual router or anything like that, I don't know if you have IP routing in that scenario.   There is probably software or some configuration that could make that work (perhaps designating one of the computers as the gateway), but I don't think it's as simple as just plugging in the ethernet cable.

Comment: Is it achievable if there's a router connected to both but does not have access to the internet?

Comment: @AryanArora - Yes, if things are properly configured.  That would be the same as a home network with the internet unplugged or down.  Traffic on the local home network works just fine.